# Horizontally aligning divs using margins and floats

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin

I've got 3 divs - Each of these in a parent div with a width of 100%. CSS:

```
 .parentDiv {
  height: 454px;
  width: 100% auto;
}
.Div1, .Div2, .Div3{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 434px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.Div1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 351px;
}
.Div2 {
  width: 351px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
.Div3 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 351px;
}
```

The Divs are ordered in the same way they are in the CSS, in the HTML.
Yet, the result of this is that the left element (Div1) is in the correct place, the supposedly centred element is centred (Div2) although it has margins either side of it that fill the entire parent Div. Therefore, I think this causes Div3 to overflow the parent Div and "collapse" vertically.

What I would really like to know is how to align the divs so that there is one on the left, one centred and one on the right. The previous questions regarding similar problems don't seem to help me in this case :/ If there was a way to shorten Div2's margins so that they could allow all of the Divs to remain aligned correctly in the parent div - I would really love to know how (Preferably not using absolute pixel measurements)

This probably made no sense - But I really do appreciate all suggestions/answers :)
Cheers

Additional Explanation:
This is what it is at the moment:
Div1Div2Div3
What I would like:
Div1         Div2          Div3
The length of this is equal to the parentDiv

HTML (For this section)

```
    <div class="parentDiv">

        <div class="Div1">
            <!--Insert code here-->
        </div>

        <div class="Div2">
            <!--Insert code here-->
        </div>

        <div class="Div3">
            <!--Insert code here-->
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your html codes?

Comment: Similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141292/how-to-create-a-3-column-responsive-layout) see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to worry, managed to finally solve it using some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(".parentDiv").css("width")
    var width = width.replace("px","");
    var width = parseInt(width,10);
    var val1 = width-1073;
    var val2 = val1/2;
    $(".Div2").css("margin-left",val2);
    $(".Div2").css("margin-right",val2);

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var width = $(".parentDiv").css("width");
        var width = width.replace("px","");
        var width = parseInt(width,10);
        if(1073>width) {
            $(".Div3").css("display","hidden")
        }
        else {
            var val1 = width-1073;
            var val2 = val1/2;
            $(".Div2").css("margin-left",val2);
            $(".Div2").css("margin-right",val2);
        }
    });
```

I know it's not the most efficient nor pretty code ever written (I'm really new to jQuery and Javascript) - But it does work :) I'd like to apologise to anybody who was kind enough to try to decipher my appalling explanations :/

Note that I also set the Child Div's positioning type to absolute, then Div1 as left: 0; and Div3 as right: 0;

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION # 1**

You may see the [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npralhad/3dzjfe1u/3/).

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="Div1">
        Div 1 - Some text
    </div>        
    <div class="Div2">
        Div 2 - Some text
    </div>       
    <div class="Div3">
        Dive 3 - Some text
    </div>           
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
 .parentDiv {
  height: 454px;
  width: 100% auto;
}
.parentDiv div{
    float:left;
}
.Div1, .Div2, .Div3{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 434px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
.Div1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 351px;
}
.Div2 {
  width: 351px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.Div3 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 351px;
}
```

**SOLUTION # 2**

Please go through the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npralhad/3dzjfe1u/5/).

Here is the complete source code:

- I have added margin-left to all 3 divs.

Code:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
 .parentDiv {
  height: 454px;
  width: 100% auto;
}
.parentDiv div{
    /* float:left; */
}
.Div1, .Div2, .Div3{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 434px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
.Div1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 351px;
}
.Div2 {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 361px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 351px;  
}
.Div3 {
    margin-left: 714px;
    width: 351px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="Div1">
        Div 1 - Some text
    </div>        
    <div class="Div2">
        Div 2 - Some text
    </div>       
    <div class="Div3">
        Dive 3 - Some text
    </div>           
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**As you will observe:**

1. I have removed `margin` from `Div2`.
2. I have added new css for `.parentDiv div` - so you may please remove the `float` from other individual divs.
3. You may like to remove the `BORDER` of the divs.

**My Suggestion**

4. I suggest to use Responsive Breakpoints to make your page **Responsive**.

Comment: I may be doing this wrong, but when I try this all of the divs are shifted to the left of the parent - rather than one being spaced ledft, one in the direct centre and one on the far right.

Comment: Yeah, I am :/ Sorry, I think my description is failing me. Let me rephrase: Div1 should be on the far left. Then, a gap until Div2 which is centred among the parentDiv and then another gap until Div 3     rather than them all floating to the left of the parentDiv, I would like them to separate out as shown whereby the Div2 has a margin either side of it at the automatic right length to centre it (Hope that makes a little more sense) :)

Comment: I have updated my answer with Solution # 2. Fiddle link for this is - http://jsfiddle.net/npralhad/3dzjfe1u/5/. I would like to suggest you to upload the `WIREFRAME` of the output that you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this on div2:

```
 .Div2 {
      width: 351px;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better solution than floating elements, change it for display:inline-block elements.

```
.parentDiv > div { font-size: 1em; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
.parentDiv { font-size : 0; }
```

This works responsive and is better than float. Float is only for floated elements, not for design layout. It's a false and most recurrent technique by some front-end developers. Thanks to floats, you can see thousands of tons of clearfix along the pages. It is cruft, crap.